# Pandas groupby same date over the years (group 2007-01-01 with 2008-01-01 etc.)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas-dataframe which contains the temperature for every hour. I already grouped to the mean temperature of the day with:

`weather = weather.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='D')).mean()`

to:

```
                 temp
date                 
2007-01-01  11.457143
2007-01-02   9.229167
2007-01-03   9.085106
2007-01-04  11.234043
2007-01-05  11.239130
...               ...
2016-12-27   8.437500
2016-12-28   5.145833
2016-12-29   3.739130
2016-12-30   7.020833
2016-12-31   3.729167

[3653 rows x 1 columns]
```

**how can I get the mean temperature of the same date over the years?
For example the mean temperature from 2007-01-01 / 2008-01-01 / 2009-01-01 and so on?**

My data needs to look something like this, with 01-01 being the mean temperature from the first of january over the years:

```
01-01   12
01-02   15
01-03   13
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by month and day:

```
weather = weather.groupby([weather.index.month, weather.index.day])[['val']].mean()
```

You obtain a series indexed with pairs `(month, day)`. You can go one step further if you want the index to be strings `'month-day'`:

```
weather.index = pd.Series(weather.index.values).apply(lambda x: '{0:02d}-{1:02d}'.format(*x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataframe:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=1000, freq='D')
    df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val' : np.random.randint(low=12, high=100, size=len(rng))})
```

Get a month date column

```
df['month_day'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%m-%d'))
```

Groupby the month_day

```
df.groupby('month_day').mean()
```